# Can't bind to formControl

Tags: angular, typescript

I've gone through dozens of answers here and still couldn't figure out why it's not working. Usually it has to do with not importing ReactiveFormsModule but I've done that. I pretty much copied and pasted the code from the [Official Docs Example](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fname-editor%2Fname-editor.component.html).

Error: Can't bind to formControl since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NameEditorComponent } from './name-editor/name-editor.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NameEditorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-editor',
  templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.css']
})
export class NameEditorComponent {
  name = new FormControl('');

  updateName() {
    this.name.setValue('Nancy');
  }
}
```

template:

```
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input id="name" type="text" [formControl]="name">

<p>Value: {{ name.value }}</p>

<button type="button" (click)="updateName()">Update Name</button>
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: What version of `@angular/forms` are you using?

Comment: I know you've probably already tried this, but sometimes just closing and reopening your IDE fixes this. Assuming it's the linter giving you the error.

Comment: @Pablo, remember that you need import the ReactiveFormsModule **in** the module where you declare the `NameEditorComponent`. (not in main.module)

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Well it turns out everything works fine, but the error message and squiggly line don't go away even after I close and reopen the IDE.

Comment: @PabloAguirredeSouza yeah just a linting error, if in VSCode, head to your command palette and find the command `Angular: Restart Angular Language Server`, that should do it. It could also be a different linting extension, the error should have a tag like `ngtsc` or `eslint` to tell you which linter it is. Every linter should have a similar restart command.

Answer (score 2):

Tried it out and it works fine for me.
I don't see any issue with your code either.

Looks like dummy error.
Restart IDE and app once - it should work fine.